# Python HTTPS requests slow with openssl 3

Tags: python, python-requests, openssl, ubuntu-22.04

I updated from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and now all my python scripts with HTTPS requests are much slower than before (0.7 sec vs. ~2 sec).

```
import requests
import threading
import time

def req():

    r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')


for i in range(10):

    thread_amount = 50
    threads = []
    s = time.time()
    for i in range(thread_amount):
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target = req))
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    e = time.time()
    total_time = e - s
    print(f"total time: {total_time} s")
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is caused by openssl 3.0.2 and any other openssl 3.x.x version. That's why I tried to install openssl 1.1.1s, which worked fine, but afterwards you have to re-compile python to make it use openssl 1.1.1s. Unfortunately this breaks everything for me. I need a solution which works with openssl 3.

Answer (score -1):

try disabling the verification of the SSL certificate (this should increase loading times) (also this works with the latest version of OpenSSL

```py
def req():
    r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/', verify=False)
```